# Replace CAPS key functionality

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, replace

Is there a way to override the functionality of the caps lock key? I think its the most useless key ever, and I want to write a program that can toggle some system preferences with CAPS lock.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  There are plenty of programs out there that let you remap keys.

Comment: Is there a program which can do this already? I want to toggle system preferences for F-Keys (F1, F2, etc) using CAPS lock key.

If there is no program, do you know any API description for replacing keys like that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an existing application which can accomplish this:
https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/